# Javascript Form does not recognise validation

Tags: javascript, html

I have this piece of code (I removed anything not necessary) but whenever I click submit for the form, it skips the validation and sends the information to the site and displays it there. Im trying to get it to validate the spaces I have first and display an alert if it isnt there before it goes there. Bit stuck, have looked at all possibilities so any help would be good. I didnt code in the 'script' code but rest assured its there.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7d7c935add71abb0b36870d9a68e7240

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/fero6np0/

```
function(){}
```

Comment: First of all, you can't put Javascript into yor `<head>` tag you need to put it into `<script>` tag. Don't set you submit method inline it's not good practice, set via `addEventListener` but if you still wanna do it inline-way do it like so `onsubmit="validateForm"`.

Comment: @Krusader I already mentioned that i had the script tag in the post. I just forgot to put it into the post. Your suggestion via onsubmit="validateForm" doesnt work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function error(mess){
  alert(mess);
  return false;
}
function validateForm(){
  var object;
  validated = true;

  if(document.getElementById('fname').value == ""){
    return error("Please fill in all fields.");
  }
  if(document.getElementById('lname').value == ""){
    return error("Please fill in all fields.");
  }
  return true
}


Checkbox is on your charge.

HTML:
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="POST" action=".">
<p>
  *First Name:<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</p>
<p>
  *Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</p>
<p>
Do you agree for your information to be used as per our Privacy Policy?<br/>
*Agree: <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" id="privacy">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="Reset form">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
</form>
```

Note the IDs.

Comment: Sorry, Didnt see that you had posted again. The problem was that name was missing from form. It works fine now, fixing up the code now as well. TY

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bug here:

```
26: object = validated;
```

If `validated` is false, `object` is false.

Comment: How is that supposed to solve my problem. That wasnt in there initially but i just put it there for the sake of trying. It doesnt solve what im trying to do

Comment: You'll solve your proble piece after piece. It's a piece.

Comment: Okay so whats the next piece? Because your advice didnt move me too far.

Comment: Because ID and NAME are NOT the same things.

Comment: your right, that did solve it. Seems to work now. For some reason because name was missing, it wouldnt even attempt the formValidation function (I tested it by putting an alert right at the start, didnt activate. So thanks for that, it completely missed my eyes. Ill go ahead and tidy up the code and move redundant code like your first example. Cheers.

Comment: I didnt think they were the same things, I was just using it to format it in CSS. I didnt realise form needed a name.